# Flask - SQLAlchemy italicizing text imported from db

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a application that I am pulling data from fields in MySQL database.  In some of these fields a some of the text needs to be italicized. For example, in species.html I have a table data "species.Notes" that I am pulling out from the MySQL database.  That will render something like this on the page when the application is rendered:

Example:

Tall three tip sagebrush is associated with gray horsebrush (Tetradymia canescens).

The text in parenthesis (i.e. species name) need to be italicized, and the rest needs to remain normal text.  I have tried storing the information in the MySQL database with html tags around Tetradymia canescens

```
<i></i>
<html><i></i></htm>
```

but that did not work, and I have not been able to find other suggestions online.

For reference (if needed?), here is how the information is being pulled into the html page where it will be displayed.

species.html

```
 <tr>
    <th scope="row">Additional Species Information</th>
    <td colspan="3">{{ species.Notes }}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jinja filters to introduce the italics tag like this:

```
<td colspan="3">
    {{ species.Notes|replace('(', '<i>(')|replace(')', ')</i>')|safe }}
</td>
```

Ideally you'd preprocess the text with a regex expression and pass it to the template with the tags already there, then you would just need the safe filter alone.

Comment: @ PJ Santoro thanks again.  The Jinja filter works great.  When I have more free time I will look into regex expressions, and see if I cannot get a handle on that.